# Returning Columns from Associated Table in Model.all

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Summary:

I have a model with a few "belongs_to" associations and when I call Model.all (or another custom method if need be) I want to not only return all columns of Model, but also one column from each of the associated Models.  Basically instead of just returning the ID's of the associated Models I want to get a more friendly attribute like "name".

Using Rails 3.2.x

Model Details:

I have five models, basically for data normalization.

```
class ActionItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :action_item_status
  belongs_to :prod_ops_acceptance
  belongs_to :action_item_priority
  belongs_to :incident_ticket
  <truncated the rest>
end

class IncidentTicket < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :number
  has_many :action_items
  validates_presence_of :number
end

class ActionItemPriority < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name
 has_many :action_items
 validates_presence_of :name
end

class ActionItemStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :action_items
  validates_presence_of :name
end

class ProdOpsAcceptance < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :action_items
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Attempted Solutions:

I've tried many combinations of things including using ActionItem.includes and ActionItem.joins to no avail.  The latest thing I tried is (trying only for the 'number' attribute of the IncidentTicket model to start with...)

```
ActionItem.all(
  select: 'action_items.title, incident_tickets.number',
  joins: 'INNER JOIN incident_tickets
          ON action_items.incident_ticket_id = incident_tickets.id')
```

The above only returns the 'title' attribute from the ActionItem model and not the 'number' attribute from the IncidentTicket model despite the SQL looking correct.  It seems like the SELECT on the joined table is completely ignored no matter what I try.

Obviously I am seriously missing something here or doing this completely wrong.  I feel like there is some ActiveRecord magic that I'm missing out on that makes this trivial.  Any help would be much appreciated!  Please let me know if you need more details, I feel like this is kind of difficult to explain...

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work for you:

```
action_items =
  ActionItem.joins(:incident_ticket, :action_item_priority, ...)
    .select(%[ action_items.title,
               incident_tickets.number AS incident_ticket_number,
               action_item_priorities.name AS action_item_priority_name,
               ... ]
    )
    .all

logger.info(action_items.first.incident_ticket_number)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Tried that with no luck, still doesn't return the columns of the associated table.

1.9.3-p484 :004 > ActionItem.joins(:incident_ticket).select('action_items.title, incident_tickets.number').last
  ActionItem Load (0.8ms)  SELECT action_items.title, incident_tickets.number FROM `action_items` INNER JOIN `incident_tickets` ON `incident_tickets`.`id` = `action_items`.`incident_ticket_id` ORDER BY `action_items`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<ActionItem title: "this is an action item">

Comment: Please be more specific. What query does ActiveRecord perform? What does the collection returned look like? What attributes do the objects in the collection have?

Comment: 1.9.3-p484 :004 > ActionItem.joins(:incident_ticket).select('action_items.title, incident_tickets.number').last
  ActionItem Load (0.8ms)  SELECT action_items.title, incident_tickets.number FROM `action_items` INNER JOIN `incident_tickets` ON `incident_tickets`.`id` = `action_items`.`incident_ticket_id` ORDER BY `action_items`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<ActionItem title: "this is an action item">

Comment: Same result, only returns the title from action_items.  For what it's worth, I get "ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'incident_tickets' was not found on ActionItem; perhaps you misspelled it?" if I use ":incident_tickets" for the first argument of .joins but if I change it to ":incident_ticket" it runs but still only returns title.

Comment: What does `logger.info(action_items.first.incident_ticket_number)` print? (And you're correct, singular `:incident_ticket` is needed in `joins` because that's the name of the association. I updated my answer to reflect that.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71621/discussion-between-irlrobot-and-jordan).

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing for now is creating a method that returns an array containing the results of ActionItem.all with the additional attributes I want injected in.  This can probably be optimized, but I haven't spent any more time focusing on that just yet:

```
def self.all_with_extras
  action_items_with_extras = []
  action_items = ActionItem.all.to_json
  JSON.parse(action_items).each do |ai|
    extras = {
      'incident_ticket_number' => IncidentTicket.find(ai['incident_ticket_id']).number,
      'status' => ActionItemStatus.find(ai['action_item_status_id']).name,
      'priority' => ActionItemPriority.find(ai['action_item_priority_id']).name,
      'acceptance' => ProdOpsAcceptance.find(ai['prod_ops_acceptance_id']).name
    }
    with_extras = ai.merge(extras)
    action_items_with_extras.append(with_extras)
  end # each
  action_items_with_extras
end # def
```